# How can I bind to an Entry's "focused" event with Reactive?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, reactive

I'm trying to bind to an text Entry fields "focused" event using reactive but my code is failing to compile.

Here's what I'm doing now, which works fine:

```
Entry _qty; // at class level
_qty.Focused += (s, e) => { /* do stuff */ };
```

**Attempt**

But I'd like to do something like this instead:

```
// class level

IObservable<string> _qtyFocusObservable;
Entry _qty;


// in a setup function

_qtyFocusObservable =
    Observable 
        .FromEventPattern<EventHandler<FocusEventArgs>>(
            x => _qty.Focused += x,
            x => _qty.Focused -= x
        );
```

**Problem**

I've tried quite a few variations of the code above and I get compiler errors saying that the compiler can't implicitly convert from *whatever type I specify* to `System.EventHandler<System.EventHandler<Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs>>`, even if the type I specify is indeed `System.EventHandler<System.EventHandler<Xamarin.Forms.FocusEventArgs>>`.

### Question

How do I bind to my **Entry**'s `Focused` event using reactive?

Comment: Are you trying to get the current text into the Observable<string> when the Entry is focused?

Comment: @WilliamCorncobDecker I'm not, I just want to perform a task when the _qty text field is focused on. I'm new to reactive so I tried manipulating an example I saw online to suit my needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to get a basic observable working from an event I usually structure like so:

`var focusObservable = Observable.FromEventPattern<EventHandler, FocusEventArgs>(
    x => _qty.Focused += x.Invoke, 
    x => _qty.Focused -= x.Invoke);`

Then when I need to do something from that observable event I link a command to it like so:

`var doStuffCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncTask(DoStuffAsync);
focusObservable.InvokeCommand(doStuffCommand);`

With a DoStuffAsync implementation of something like this:

`public async Task DoStuffAsync(object value, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
{
    // Do stuff here
}`

I'm still fairly new to Reactive as well but this (should?) get you going in the right direction.

Cheers, and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

So, after a year of using ReactiveUI, this is how I fire an event when focusing an input.

```
var focusedObservable =
    Observable
        .FromEventPattern<FocusEventArgs>(
            x => _totalBirds.Focused += x,
            x => _totalBirds.Focused -= x)
        .Select(x => x.EventArgs.IsFocused);

    // fires when focused
    focusedObservable 
        .WhenIsTrue() // extension method, basically .Where(x => x == true)
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .InvokeCommand(this, x => DoSomething)
        .DisposeWith(ControlBindings); // extension that uses composite disposable

    // fires when changing state back to unfocused
    focusedObservable
        .WhenIsFalse() // extension method, basically .Where(x => x == false)
        .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
        .InvokeCommand(this, x => x.ViewModel.DoSomethingElse)
        .DisposeWith(ControlBindings); // extension that uses composite disposable
```

This is pretty straight forward, if you need to see any additional code, let me know. Also, if you want to snag the `.DisposeWith` extension you can grab it [here](https://github.com/TheEightBot/Reactive-Examples/blob/master/ReactiveExtensionExamples/Extensions/IObservableExtensions.cs).